# nothing appear in my applet?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why there is no thing appear in my applet ?
I started to learn java using eclipse before two days, but when I come to image part there is no thing appear in my applet

My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CityScape extends JApplet {
    setSize(800,500);
    super.paint(g);
    Image img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"aaa.png");
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
}}
```

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in the question.

Comment: Create an HTML File that Includes the Applet